# What can I use to hang up grocery bags?

Tags: walls, hanging

I'd like a good solution for hanging up grocery bags and other miscellaneous things on the wall. Basic hooks would do the trick, but some things like to slip off it (like too many grocery bags). To combat this travesty, I thought to have a carabiner attached to a wall, so it seems my options are:

- http://www.woss.com/oblong-stainless-steel-eye-pad-600lbs-working-weight/
- http://www.berkeleypoint.com/products/hardware/S0230-0000.html

Remaining questions:

1. Does it have another name that I don't know of?
2. Do you guys think the carabiner solution is a decent one as well?

Comment: The problem I see with the carabiner idea, even if the two handed operation was acceptable, is that the hook ends up hanging in the wrong orientation to easily engage the handles of the grocery bags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have suggested are great ideas, but perhaps a bit overkill (unless you intend to hang full reusable grocery bags, gallon of milk included).

The best solution I've come across in similar storage searches, is to create a decorative, but sturdy rail, mounted on your wall. They make similar systems for garages that are effectively modular, and typically an engineered metal solution. A nice 1"x3" of finish grade, poplar or similar (with or without trim, paint, etc) Could be attached with appropriate hardware to the studs of your wall, similar to how people might mount a chair rail.

Then, any number of hooks, loops, carabiners, etc. could be easily attached to this sturdy, yet decorative runner. Otherwise, unless you only mount on studs, you'll find drywall anchors will work out as drywall has a poor working performance.

Depending on the statement you're looking to make, and the location of your project, I might suggest a board with several light duty recessed pan fitting rings. These will certainly be cheaper than what you had suggested.

[image]

These could be neat in a storage area. Look [HERE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C5RGSDE) on Amazon.

Now, specifically for storing empty grocery bags (reusable or otherwise), the best solution I've ever seen is a "grocery bag sock" or "stocking". It acts as both storage and a dispenser. That is personally how I manage a myriad of reusable grocery bags at my home.

Good luck and let us know how it turns out!

Answer (score 1):

There are millions of available types of coat hooks, most of which will look a lot nicer than the carabiners you proposed.

The trouble with both of your suggestions is that they require two hands to get things off... one hand to unclip them and the other hand to remove the object. As such they will eventually drive you crazy.

Comment: Good point on the two hands to remove the objects. I think my brain gravitated to the most hipster solution possible which obviously had to include a carabiner. ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I really like your ideas but can also understand the previous suggestion of having something that you can use with one hand.

I had a couple of ideas.  One is to use large hooks intended for bicycles or tools. Here's one example (below in red) but they make different sizes and shapes.

[image]

Another smaller makeshift solution would be to get one of type pictured below and mount it on its side, using screws through the short protrusion into the wall so that the large protrusion acts as the upward-facing hook.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Where did you find that second one? I'm trying to search for similar pieces like extended L-brackets or something and not finding anything like what you have there.